# How to import React component from another file (w/out React app)

Tags: reactjs, import, react-component

I am adding some React scripts to my HTML templates and I am trying to separate React code in separate files. I have not started a full-blown React app. I am therefore trying to import smaller components from other files into a "main" React script.

Here is my directory structure:

> react 
> ----components 
> --------**Tag.js** 
> --------**Definition.js** 
> ----**Definitions.js**

Here is my code for **Definitions.js** (the "main" React script):

```
import Definition from './components/Definition';

class Definitions extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return <Definition definition={definition} />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Definitions />, document.querySelector("#definitions"));
```

Here is my code for **Definition.js**:

```
import Tag from './Tag';

class Definition extends React.Component {
    ...

    render() {
        return <Tag tag={tag} />;
    }
}

export default Definition;
```

This code is not rendering any component. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to clarify how exact it's not working. Nothing rendered? Error?

Comment: You are missing a dot here: `import Definition from '../components/Definition';`

Comment: @SakoBu, did not work.

Comment: Do you export the components? Try making a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-t80qj

Comment: @DennisVash No, I did not export. I added the export statements to my question, but still not working.

Comment: Just make a sandbox and simulate your exports... Then we will be able to see your mistakes

Comment: Anyways my guess its because of wrong render target: `document.querySelector("#definitions")` and has nothing to do with exports

Comment: The sandbox is too complex to recreate since my actual code is more complex than the one in the question. However, it did complain about the names 'React' and 'ReactDOM' not defined.

Comment: Thats something you should mention... Your question is lack of information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beforehand you need to render the React application to the actual DOM using `ReactDOM.render`, so you need to import it and target a valid element:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return <>React App Example</>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);

// target a valid element in index.html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Thats the reason why you not getting any errors, you don't even initial the application.

Then its just a normal import-export.

Please refer to React docs [how to initial a React app](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

`Button.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    // ...
  }
}

export default Button; // Don’t forget to use export default!
```

`DangerButton.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from './Button'; // Import a component from another file

class DangerButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Button color="red" />;
  }
}

export default DangerButton;
```

From: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/